# Fastest way to take

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a 3-dimensional tensor A of size (M,N,N). I also have a weight vector p of length M. I want to compute

[image]

The dimension N can be large so I want to implement it in the efficient way possible. I am using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
temp=np.array([p[m]*A[m] for m in range(M)])
B=sum(temp);
```

I want to know if there are much faster and efficient ways of implementing this. The reason why this is important is because when N is large, the above variable temp stores M of these N*N matrices. So I am thinking we can use a "for loop" maybe but I read that for loops are slower than list comprehensions.

Answer (score 2):

At least from the tensors I tested it on, this snippet is up to 3x faster:

```
sum(np.einsum('ij...,i->ij...', A, p))
```

Here's a comparison for the various methods that were shared:

```
base      = sum(np.array([p[m]*A[m] for m in range(M)]))
einsum1   = sum(np.einsum('ij...,i->ij...', A, p))
einsum2   = np.einsum('ijk,i->jk', A, p)
einsum3   = np.einsum('ij...,i->j...', A, p)
dot       = p.dot(A.reshape(A.shape[0],-1)).reshape(A.shape[1],-1)
tensordot = np.tensordot(p, A, (0, 0))
```

---

for M = 1000, N = 100 (compared to base):

```
einsum1   = 1.11x
einsum2   = 5.83x
einsum3   = 6.26x
dot       = 8.60x
tensordot = 9.83x
```

Comment: What about np.tensordot(p,A,(0,0)) ?

Comment: The `tensordot` one is considerably faster the bigger the tensor (10x faster when M=1000, N=100)

Comment: You mean faster than the above einsum method?

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo Shouldn't you be doing `np.einsum('ijk,i->jk', A, p)`?

Comment: Or `np.einsum('ij...,i->j...', A, p)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
In [24]: A=np.arange(3*2*2).reshape(3,2,2)    
In [25]: p=np.array([1,2,3])

In [26]: temp=np.array([p[m]*A[m] for m in range(len(p))])
In [27]: sum(temp)  # python sum
Out[27]: 
array([[32, 38],
       [44, 50]])

In [28]: np.einsum('i...,i->...',A,p)
Out[28]: 
array([[32, 38],
       [44, 50]])
```

`ijk,i->jk` also works.

While not necessarily fastest, `temp` can be calculated with simple broadcasting.  `np.sum(..., axis=0)` is the equivalent of Python `sum()`.

```
In [30]: (A*p[:,None,None]).sum(axis=0)
Out[30]: 
array([[32, 38],
       [44, 50]])
```